# Advanced Selectors in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have the following code in jQuery which, when you enter text into a textfield (`#searchServices`), it will fade out links which do not contain that text and it will fade in links that do contain the text.

How can I do this in ExtJS?

```
$('#searchServices').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
        $('.serviceGridItem:not(:contains("' + $(this).val() + '"))').fadeOut();
        $('.serviceGridItem:contains("' + $(this).val() + '")').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
        $('.serviceGridItem').fadeIn();
    }
})
```

Right now, I have my textfield and my listener like so:

```
xtype: 'textfield',
enableKeyEvents: true,
listeners: {
    keyup: function(c) {
        console.log(c.getValue());
    }
}
```

My (generated) html is as such:

```
<div class="x-component x-window-item x-component-default" id="dataview-1049" tabindex="-1" style="">
    <a href="#" class="serviceGridItem">Legal Compliance</a>
    <a href="#" class="serviceGridItem">Departure Package</a>
    <a href="#" class="serviceGridItem">House Search</a>
    <a href="#" class="serviceGridItem">Language Training</a>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I have tried this but I get and error that says, "Unexpected identifier."

```
Ext.query('.serviceGridItem:not(:contains("' + c.getValue() + '"))').hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Ext.dom.Query.select instead.

For example...

```
var dom = Ext.dom.Query.select('.serviceGridItem');
for(var i=0;i<dom.length;i++){
    var el = Ext.get(dom[i]);
    if(el.dom.outerText.indexOf("Legal") != -1){
        el.hide();
    }
}
```

This one should hide the one that contains "Legal" in its value

Comment: Same result.  Please note that I am not trying to get all elements, just the ones that contain certain text in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful.  I will accept this as an answer, but it sucks that ExtJS cant just do `Ext.query('.serviceGridItem:not(:contains("' + c.getValue() + '"))').hide();`.  It seems ExtJS doesn't support nested selectors like this.  I posted another question with a more specific example and a jsfiddle here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785001/extjs-bug-selector-not-working-properly