# ExtJs Bug? Selector not working properly

Tags: javascript, extjs

It appears that this selector is not working in ExtJS:

```
Ext.select('.serviceGridItem:not(:first)')
```

It is selecting all items, whereas it should only select the last three (there are four total).  See the jsfiddle linked below and look at your console for the result.

This is the result:

```
Ext.select('.serviceGridItem')
    constructor {elements: Array[4], el: constructor, self: function, superclass: Object, config: emptyFn…}
Ext.select('.serviceGridItem:first')
    constructor {elements: Array[1], el: constructor, self: function, superclass: Object, config: emptyFn…}
Ext.select('.serviceGridItem:not(:first)')
    constructor {elements: Array[4], el: constructor, self: function, superclass: Object, config: emptyFn…}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="x-component x-window-item x-component-default" id="dataview-1049" tabindex="-1" style="">
    <a href="#" class="serviceGridItem">Legal Compliance</a>
    <a href="#" class="serviceGridItem">Departure Package</a>
    <a href="#" class="serviceGridItem">House Search</a>
    <a href="#" class="serviceGridItem">Language Training</a>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    console.log(Ext.select('.serviceGridItem'));
    console.log(Ext.select('.serviceGridItem:first'));
    console.log(Ext.select('.serviceGridItem:not(:first)')); // should return Array[3] not Array[4]
});
```

The JSFiddle (look in your console for the result):

http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/5/

Is this a bug or is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really tell you how the `:first` pseudo-selector is supposed to behave. It's not part of the CSS3 standard and I think it was introduced with [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/). ExtJS apparently seems to interpret it in some way, but I couldn't find anything about it in the docs.

However, you could try using the CSS3 [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#first-child-pseudo) selector:

```
Ext.select('.serviceGridItem:not(:first-child)');
```

which seems to work just fine in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/6/

Comment: Thanks, that's better than nothing.  But, the reason I posted this bug is because of another bug I found whereby `:contains()` doesn't seem to work at all.  What do you think regarding this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/7/

Comment: Same here, not really part of the CSS spec ([anymore](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#content-selectors)). However, it seems to work if you omit the quotes `""` ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/8/))

Comment: Very nice!  I never thought of that.